# How to synchronize related custom view look on different viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift

My setup is two viewcontrollers with 50 custom views from .xib on each. Custom views on one viewcontroller are different from custom views on another only by design layout, functionality is duplicated. When a custom view is clicked on one viewcontroller, it changes the image and color. My goal is to show the same image and color of the corresponding custom view on the other viewcontroller.

Comment: It seems your question desperately lacks details: Essential code snippets, layout screenshots, what you tried, and what you got.

Comment: Directing me to a design pattern will do for me. I believe the singleton pattern will not work since there are 50+ instances of each class. Creating outlets and reassigning the proreties in ViewDidLoad is a kind of "meh" solution due to maintenance hell if more custom views are added in the future.

Comment: The only pattern that comes to my mind about such a high level question is Dependency Injection. How about creating a bunch of views, some of which share presentation logic? You could inject same view models or presenters or whatever to different views.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.